# ALSA buffer xrun when recording with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, alsa, buffer

Is there any way to increase the ALSA buffer size?

When running this command:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1 -ar 44100 -b 64k output.mp3
```

I get a "ALSA buffer xrun" before my system locks up

```
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 2480.999037, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'lastzzz.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[alsa @ 0x1c04660] ALSA buffer xrun.
```

Here is my version of ALSA:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /proc/asound/version
 Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.25.
```

Just to make sure:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install alsa
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 Note, selecting 'alsa-base' instead of 'alsa'
 alsa-base is already the newest version.
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: "locks up"? I'd guess this is the cause of the xrun.

Comment: yes, running top in a separate window shows the cpu gradually increasing until it reaches 100% cpu

Comment: Which process eats the CPU?

Comment: the ffmpeg process has an increasing cpu load until it reaches 100% and I think it is because of the "Alsa buffer xrun"

Comment: setting the `thread_queue_size` value to a large value might be helpful

Comment: thanks @Alf running with -v verbose showed this suggestion:
[alsa @ 0x561966b34540] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)

Comment: @Kevin try a value of e.g. `thread_queue_size 1024`